# Irreducibility and flat morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a quasi projective $k$-variety ($k=\bar k$) and $X\rightarrow Y$ a flat morphism with proper (over $k$) integral $d$-dimensional ($d>0$) fibers over closed points. Can $X$ be reducible?

Comment: You probably want $Y$ irreducible, otherwise the answer is obviously no. If $Y$ is irreducible, the answer is yes: see Harris' *Algebraic Geometry - A First Course*, Theorem 11.14.